# Creating Map from scanned image

Tags: java, android, image, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a (Googlemap-esq) object from an image. This is going to be architects building plans scanned in, probably to something like a JPEG. In a native android app I want to have an object I can drop pins on and then click the pins for a info bubble etc.

I know Google provide functionality that lets you upload, create FloorPlans but this isn't really what I want. The end result would be perfect, but I can use a scanner to create them.

What sort of technology can be recommended, or do I just implement a Co-Ords system and overlay it?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps uses a tiling system because the map can be very big. For example a morton curve can recursively subdivide the surface. It's similar to a quadtree. In relational database there is a spatial index usually a r-tree or a hilbert curve. If you can use a database you can use the point datatype or you can write your own r-tree. When you have many overlapping pins maybe a quadtree is better.

Comment: Apologies I seem to have confused the issue with too much information in the question. What I am looking for here is the best way of creating a map object from an image. Dropping things onto it can come later, i just wanted to give some idea of direction so that I didn't start down the wrong path early on.

Comment: Hmmm. I think a r-tree is a good datastucture for a map object. Maybe you can elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: In the end I would like a android app to control a PA Speaker system, these are all on a wireless network. I have an app that is used for selecting the units you want to control and then open a "call" to those units, I use the Google API for this as they are outside. I need a similar solution to represent the location of speakers inside a building, for example a school, by marking the locations with dots or pins on a JPEG image which will be a scanned copy of the floor plans.

Comment: Maybe you need a transformation? Something with a ratio? A morton curve transform 2d data to 1d data ? I hope it helps?